# How to use activeforeground option in button widget of tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, button

Well I am New to Tkinter, and my question is simple, in the button widget there is activeforeground option and I want to know how to use it.

Comment: I think that `activeforeground` is the colour of the text inside the button while the button is being pressed - by holding how left click.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify a Button in tkinter like this: `Button(<parent>, text=<text>, activeforeground=<colour>,....)`
as activeforeground is a key word argument, you just put it in the brackets and give it a color. Or what exactly are you trying to do?

This is a simple window with a button, you can see how the activeforeground is implemented here and what happens when you click the button.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import*

root = tkinter.Tk()

Button1 = tkinter.Button(root,text="click me!",activeforeground="red") #<---- HERE
Button1.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor=CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

This page provides a list of the different keywords:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_button.htm

Comment: First of all those are key word arguments and not methods. Second of all, This thing that you wrote: `Button("your window", "method1","method2"....methodn")` can easily be interpreted wrongly. I would use: `Button(<parent>, text=<text>, activeforeground=<colour>)` and then specify that the colour and text are strings.

Comment: your description is better but yea thats pretty much what i was trying to tell

Comment: Also not really important but if you are showing a minimal example use something like: `root = tkinter.Tk()`, `button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Click me", activeforeground="red")`, `button.pack()`, and `root.mainloop()`. That simplifies the whole code to 5 lines and only uses 2 variables. The simpler your answer the more helpful it will be to OP

Comment: might be not important but it makes it clean and straight forward, thanks for your help. I hope he is able to understand this now.

Comment: well thanks for answering my question, before I checked through tutorial point website but when I implemented it , i did not use the text in the button,so it was the cause of confusion

Comment: @PriyanshuSingh Look at [this](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/button.html) website that I use. I think it is more complete and I am yet to find any errors/mistakes on that website.

Comment: @PriyanshuSingh if my answer solved your question, mark it please with the green check, else tell us whats still wrong